# Percussion instrument used in a USAFE Band

Tags: percussion, instrument-identification

We went to a concert last night by the U.S. Air Forces in Europe Band [(USAFE Band)](http://www.usafeuropeband.af.mil/).
I'm looking for the name of [this instrument](http://www.usafeuropeband.af.mil/shared/media/photodb/photos/2014%5C02%5C120711-F-KM040-143.JPG).

[image: Percussion instrument]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't find the specific model, but they look like a set of [tubular bells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_bells).

Comment: Those are indeed a set of tubular bells. Also known as chimes in the US.

Comment: @cjm, a [chime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chime_(bell_instrument)) *(singular)* is when there are les than 23 bells ;-)